# Using AGGREGATE function to extract the maximum value in an array throws up an error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what my "code" looks like :

```
=AGGREGATE(4;3;{4;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!})
```

All I want is, for the AGGREGATE function to, in this case, return "4". Instead I keep getting a #Value! error.
Alternatively, can this be extracted using a combination of other functions?
I would be grateful for any tips and/or suggestions.

This is what I'm trying to do; replace my TRUE values with a number and later extract that number `{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}/{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}*{4;14;18;28;40;55;57;64}`

Comment: Thanks, but if i have understood correctly, the "3" option should ignore the errors.

Comment: I have edited the main post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the argument is an array, and not a range, you have to use one of the array functions (#14 and higher, if I recall correctly):

```
=AGGREGATE(14,3,{4;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!},1)
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but it unfortunately doesn't seem to work 

=AGGREGATE(14;3;((F4=$D$13:$D$20)/(F4=$D$13:$D$20)*($D$13:$D$20)))

Comment: @neutronhammer it works here given both array constants you posted in your question.  Without original data hard to tell where your problem is.

Comment: CORRECTION: It does now! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @neutronhammer Glad to help.

Comment: @neutronhammer Yes, `k` is required for the `LARGE`, `SMALL`, `PERCENTILE.INC`, `QUARTILE.INC`, `PERCENTILE.EXC`, `QUARTILE.EXC`
functions.